Calculate the integration about Dirac Delta function
How to calculate the integration
$$\int_{-1/2}^{+\infty}\cos\left(\frac {\pi x}2\right)\delta\left(e^x\sin\left(\frac {\pi x}2\right)\right)\,\mathrm dx$$
My ideal is that let
$$e^x\sin\left(\frac {\pi x}2\right)=0$$
Then
$$x=2k$$
Because of the selectivity of Dirac Delta function, the integration can be simplify:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\cos(k\pi)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k$$
But the sum of
$$(-1)^k$$
is not convergent, I feel so confused.

Note that the relation $\delta(f(x)) = \sum_k \delta(x-x_k)$, where $\{x_k\}_k$ denote the zeros of $g(x)$, is not true in general. Instead, one has :
$$
\delta(f(x)) =\sum_k \frac{\delta(x-x_k)}{|f'(x_k)|}
$$
where the extra factor in the denominator can be interpreted as the Jacobian of the change of variable $x \mapsto f^{-1}(x)$, since these expressions have to be understood inside the integral of an inner product. In consequence, one has too :
$$
\int_A \phi(x)\delta(f(x)) \,\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{x_k \in A} \frac{\phi(x_k)}{|f'(x_k)|}
$$
In the present case, one has $x_k = 2k > -\frac{1}{2} \;\forall k \in \Bbb{N}$, with $\phi(x_k) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot 2k\right) = (-1)^k$ and
$$
f'(x_k) = \left.e^{x}\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right) + \frac{\pi}{2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)\right)\right|_{x=2k} = \frac{\pi}{2} (-1)^k e^{2k},
$$
hence finally
$$
\int \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right) \delta\left(e^x\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)\right) \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k e^{-2k} = \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{e^2}{e^2+1}
$$
with the help of the geometric series.
